# asmx webservice, soap requests with attachments

Tags: c#, iis, soap, asmx

It is my first post here, so please don't be to harsh if haven't met the standard with my question :)

I have problem setting up the webservice using asmx. Webservice runs on IIS.
Main issue is with SOAP requests with attachments. Those kind of request are send as "multipart/related". IIS returns an error upon receving request with data in this format (multipart/related). Error stayting that this kind of data is not supported.

So my question is if this error is the fault of IIS configuration, asmx limitations, or maybe something else?

WSDL looks like this:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://zgloszenia.iitech.com.pl/" xmlns:s0="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns:s1="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://zgloszenia.iitech.com.pl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS">
      <s:import namespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" />
      <s:element name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSRequest">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="model" nillable="true" type="s0:ZgloszeniaZSModelType" />
          </s:sequence>
          <s:attribute name="attachmentInfo" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:attribute name="attachmentData" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:attribute default="true" name="ignoreEmptyElements" type="s:boolean" />
          <s:attribute default="-1" name="updateconstraint" type="s:long" />
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="ZgloszeniaZSModelType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="keys" nillable="true" type="s0:ZgloszeniaZSKeysType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="instance" nillable="true" type="s0:ZgloszeniaZSInstanceType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="messages" type="s1:ArrayOfMessageType" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:attribute name="query" type="s:string" />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ZgloszeniaZSKeysType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsId" type="s1:StringType" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:attribute name="query" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="updatecounter" type="s:long" />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ZgloszeniaZSInstanceType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsId" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsUslEk" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsParametry" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsPrzyczyna" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsRozwiazanie" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsModyfikacja" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsIdZew" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsUmowa" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsPoziom" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsType" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsTresc" type="s0:ZgloszeniaZSInstanceTypeWsTresc" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsData" type="s0:DateTimeType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsImie" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsNazwisko" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsLokalizacja" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsEmail" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="WsTelefon" type="s1:StringType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="attachments" type="s1:ArrayOfAttachmentType" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:attribute name="query" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="uniquequery" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="recordid" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="updatecounter" type="s:long" />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ZgloszeniaZSInstanceTypeWsTresc">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="s0:ArrayType">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WsTresc" type="s1:StringType" />
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayType">
        <s:attribute name="type" type="s:string" />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="DateTimeType">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:dateTime">
            <s:attribute name="type" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="mandatory" type="s:boolean" />
            <s:attribute name="readonly" type="s:boolean" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSResult" type="s0:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSResponse" />
      <s:complexType name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="model" type="s0:ZgloszeniaZSModelType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="messages" type="s1:ArrayOfMessageType" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:attribute name="status" type="s0:StatusType" use="required" />
        <s:attribute name="message" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="schemaRevisionDate" type="s:date" use="required" />
        <s:attribute name="schemaRevisionLevel" type="s:int" use="required" />
        <s:attribute name="returnCode" type="s:decimal" />
        <s:attribute name="query" type="s:string" />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:simpleType name="StatusType">
        <s:restriction base="s:string">
          <s:enumeration value="SUCCESS" />
          <s:enumeration value="FAILURE" />
        </s:restriction>
      </s:simpleType>
    </s:schema>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common">
      <s:complexType name="StringType">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s:string">
            <s:attribute name="type" type="s:string" />
            <s:attribute name="mandatory" type="s:boolean" />
            <s:attribute name="readonly" type="s:boolean" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="MessageType">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s1:StringType">
            <s:attribute name="severity" type="s:int" />
            <s:attribute name="module" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfAttachmentType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="attachment" type="s1:AttachmentType" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="AttachmentType">
        <s:attribute name="href" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="contentId" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="action" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="name" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="type" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="len" type="s:int" />
        <s:attribute name="charset" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="upload.by" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="upload.date" type="s:string" />
        <s:attribute name="attachmentType" type="s:string" />
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfMessageType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="message" type="s1:MessageType" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://zgloszenia.iitech.com.pl/">
      <s:import namespace="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" />
      <s:complexType name="MessageType">
        <s:simpleContent>
          <s:extension base="s1:StringType">
            <s:attribute name="severity" type="s:int" />
            <s:attribute name="module" type="s:string" />
          </s:extension>
        </s:simpleContent>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSRequest" element="s0:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSRequest" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSResult" element="s0:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSResult" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="ZgloszeniaZSSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZS">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSSoapIn" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSSoapOut" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="ZgloszeniaZSSoap" type="tns:ZgloszeniaZSSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZS">
      <soap:operation soapAction="UpdateZS" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="ZgloszeniaZSSoap12" type="tns:ZgloszeniaZSSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="UpdateZSZgloszeniaZS">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="UpdateZS" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ZgloszeniaZS">
    <wsdl:port name="ZgloszeniaZSSoap" binding="tns:ZgloszeniaZSSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://zgloszenia.iitech.pl/zgloszeniazs.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="ZgloszeniaZSSoap12" binding="tns:ZgloszeniaZSSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://zgloszenia.iitech.pl/zgloszeniazs.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Request that must be handled by webservice (it comes from client aplication, that I don't have acces to).

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS/Common" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns3="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns3:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSRequest
            attachmentInfo="true"
            attachmentData="true"
            ignoreEmptyElements="true"
            updateconstraint="-1" xmlns:ns3="http://servicecenter.peregrine.com/PWS">
            <ns3:model>
                <ns3:keys
                    updatecounter="0"></ns3:keys>
                <ns3:instance
                    updatecounter="0">
                    <ns3:WsId
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">ZS362982</ns3:WsId>
                    <ns3:WsUslEk
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">Innovation_QSR#00@1.01.001</ns3:WsUslEk>
                    <ns3:WsParametry
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">&lt;parametry id="ZS362982"&gt;&lt;param id="1" name="Opis" war="Zgłoszenie testowe 29-10-2019"/&gt;&lt;param id="2" name="Źródłowe EK:" war="WZU#00 (HP SM)"/&gt;&lt;param id="3" name="Podkategoria:" war="Zgłoszenie od użytkownika"/&gt;&lt;param id="4" name="Typ produktu:" war="Obszar wewnętrznych i uzupełniających usług IT"/&gt;&lt;param id="5" name="Typ problemu:" war="Aplikacja HP SM - Wystąpił błąd lub wyświetla ona nieprawidłowe informacje (usługa: WZU#00)"/&gt;&lt;/parametry&gt;</ns3:WsParametry>
                    <ns3:WsIdZew
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">test13112019</ns3:WsIdZew>
                    <ns3:WsUmowa
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">Umowa z numerem</ns3:WsUmowa>
                    <ns3:WsPoziom
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">incydent standardowy</ns3:WsPoziom>
                    <ns3:WsType
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">I</ns3:WsType>
                    <ns3:WsTresc
                        type="Array">
                        <ns3:WsTresc
                            type="String"
                            mandatory="false"
                            readonly="false">Testowe zgłoszneie z załącznikiem.</ns3:WsTresc>
                        <ns3:WsTresc
                            type="String"
                            mandatory="false"
                            readonly="false">Osoba do kontaktu:</ns3:WsTresc>
                        <ns3:WsTresc
                            type="String"
                            mandatory="false"
                            readonly="false">GAL, ANONIM</ns3:WsTresc>
                        <ns3:WsTresc
                            type="String"
                            mandatory="false"
                            readonly="false">5555555555</ns3:WsTresc>
                        <ns3:WsTresc
                            type="String"
                            mandatory="false"
                            readonly="false">jakis@mail.pl</ns3:WsTresc>
                    </ns3:WsTresc>
                    <ns3:WsData
                        type="DateTime"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">2019-11-15T10:21:23+00:00</ns3:WsData>
                    <ns3:WsImie
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">Gal</ns3:WsImie>
                    <ns3:WsNazwisko
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">Anonim</ns3:WsNazwisko>
                    <ns3:WsLokalizacja
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">Miasto</ns3:WsLokalizacja>
                    <ns3:WsEmail
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">jakis@mail.pl</ns3:WsEmail>
                    <ns3:WsTelefon
                        type="String"
                        mandatory="false"
                        readonly="false">555555555</ns3:WsTelefon>
                    <ns3:attachments>
                        <ns0:attachment
                            href="cid:5dce7bed002d308280844a58"
                            contentId="cid:5dce7bed002d308280844a58"
                            action="add"
                            name="parametry_IIT.xlsx"
                            type="application/octet-stream"
                            len="11252" />
                    </ns3:attachments>
                </ns3:instance>
            </ns3:model>
        </ns3:UpdateZSZgloszeniaZSRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

On the bottom you can see how the attachment is set in the request.

Answer (score 0):

After some time I have found a solution. 
So asmx doesn't support multipart/related requests. However you can use something called soap extention. This way you can capture request, and do something with it, before it reaches the actual service. Also you can make any response you like.

More on soap extentions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/march/house-of-web-services-accessing-raw-soap-messages-in-asp-net-web-services